# Перенос текста в IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При отображении такого `"08:00-08:30"` текста внутри таблицы `IEv6` почему-то переносит на новую строку после дефиса. В `Opera`, `Firefox`, `Chrome` все нормально. Есть ли что-то типа "неразрывного тире" или другого способа исправить данный баг?

Comment: Я бы уточнил - MS must die ^.^

Comment: Я бы посоветовал даже создать такую метку))

Comment: Ну если, как выразилась MS, пить молоко 10-летней давности, то таки да, коровы must die =) Не обижайте форточников, ибо они - это я)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE разметку по-другому воспринимает. Увеличте ширину ячейки и посмотрите. А неразрывный пробле **`&nbsp;`**

Comment: Пробел-то я знаю)) А насчет ширины ячейки, то места там достаточно.

Comment: а как в другой версии IE?

Comment: 7-й также отобразил. 8-го под рукой не оказалось.

Comment: а код можете показать? Ибо вот скрин IE9 http://s017.radikal.ru/i418/1111/8f/937050c6e781.png

Comment: Все, нашел ошибку. У меня оказывается в стилях где-то было прописано `width:70px;`. Теперь отображает нормально.

Comment: Кстати, для отображения записи требуется около 80px. Так что я думаю `IE` понять можно.

Comment: ну а я про что говорил?

>Увеличте ширину ячейки и посмотрите

Comment: DemoS, посмотрите на картинку. Я думаю вы бы тоже сбились с толку если где-то далеко в коде у вас была прописана одна маленькая но решающая строчка))

Comment: Да я ничего против не имею, я про то, что надо ответ принять! Ибо будет висеть в непринятых ;)